# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([625, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1, 1]))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

```
# Training loop
from tqdm import tqdm
for epoch in range(2):
    print(f'!!epoch {epoch} is running!!')

    for i,(images, labels) in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader),total = len(train_loader)):
        # Forward pass
        model.train()
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.unsqueeze(1).type(torch.float32)
        labels= labels.to(device)

        output_logits = model(images)
        output_pred = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(output_logits))
        loss = loss_fn(labels, output_pred)
        
        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer_fn.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer_fn.step()
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}, Train Loss: {loss}')

    # test loop
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        cum_loss = 0
        cum_acc = 0
        for images_test,labels_test in test_loader:
            test_logits = model(images_test)
            test_pred = torch.round(torch.sigmoid(test_logits))

            test_loss = loss_fn(test_logits,labels_test)
            cum_loss += test_loss
            cum_acc += accuracy_fn(y_true = labels, y_pred = test_pred)
        print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}, Test Loss {cum_loss}, accuracy {cum_acc/len(test_loader)}')
```

i am currently training alexnet model. working on a jaundice dataset. i am using

```
loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer_fn = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

my final layer is

```
model.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(nn_filters,1)
```

getting 1 if normal and 0 if child has jaundice.

i am getting

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([625, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([1, 1]))
```

if i don't set batch size and

```
ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([10000, 1])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([16, 1]))
```

when i set `batch size = 16`. I just don't understand what i am doing wrong and what changes should i make.

Also

```
# transformations
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512,512)),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])

# Load the datasets
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('./images',transform=transform)

# Split dataset
train_size = int(0.8*len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size

train_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size,test_size])


# Create the dataloaders
batch_size = 16
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset,batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset,batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)
```

i am loading data like this. Is this ok?

this is how i used my model

```
def alexnet():
    model = models.alexnet(pretrained = True)
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        nn_filters = model.classifier[6].in_features
        model.classifier[6] = nn.Linear(nn_filters,1)
        model = model.to(device)
```

Comment: Post the tensor sizes of the model input and the model output. Also read the documentation for `BCEWithLogitsLoss`. That loss function applies a sigmoid, so you are introducing a huge error by applying an additional sigmoid to the model outputs.

Comment: thank you @Karl i just noticed and fixed the problem